# Sending WooCommerce mail "WC_Email_New_Order" from functions.php not working

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce

Every WooCommerce email can successfully be sent from functions.php – except the "new order" email.

**This does not send an email successfully:**

```
$mailer = WC()->mailer()->get_emails()['WC_Email_New_Order']->trigger( 1161 );
```

**But all of the following lines send an email successfully**

```
$mailer = WC()->mailer()->get_emails()['WC_Email_Cancelled_Order']->trigger( 1161 );
$mailer = WC()->mailer()->get_emails()['WC_Email_Customer_Completed_Order']->trigger( 1161 );
$mailer = WC()->mailer()->get_emails()['WC_Email_Customer_Invoice']->trigger( 1161 );
$mailer = WC()->mailer()->get_emails()['WC_Email_Customer_On_Hold_Order']->trigger( 1161 );
$mailer = WC()->mailer()->get_emails()['WC_Email_Customer_Processing_Order']->trigger( 1161 );
$mailer = WC()->mailer()->get_emails()['WC_Email_Customer_Refunded_Order']->trigger( 1161 );
$mailer = WC()->mailer()->get_emails()['WC_Email_Customer_Reset_Password']->trigger( 1161 );
$mailer = WC()->mailer()->get_emails()['WC_Email_Failed_Order']->trigger( 1161 );
```

Any idea what i am missing here? I am able to go to any order in the backend and resend the new order email successfully from the GUI.

**UPDATE**

Using this filter to override this behavior fixes the problem for me:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_new_order_email_allows_resend', '__return_true' );
```

Comment: I found the guilty, see the answer in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66604522/3730754